# upper div starts from the margin of the lower div

Tags: css, margin, css-position

as the topic says, my upper div starts from the margin of the lower div...
[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L6aa/3/)

no idea why it happens or how to fix, need help

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `top:0;` to the upper div.

http://jsfiddle.net/5L6aa/8/

Comment: it does fix the problem but I would like to know why/how it happen, and I could also use `margin-top:-10px`

Comment: Have you checked `Firefox Firebug` / `Chrome Inspector` computed `CSS`?

Answer (score 0):

your margin in #bases-container is set to 10px, so it could look like it starting after the second div, but its really only starting 10px lower because of your margin.

Comment: why it starting 10px lower, it shouldnt.. with position absolute and its location in the code...

Comment: your #container div is absolute but not your #bases-container div.